# Change the color of cells in one column when they don't match cells in another column

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I want to check if the values in one column are the same as values in another column. Whenever the values are not the same, I would like to change the color of these cells.

For example:

[image: http://i60.tinypic.com/2ai203l.png]

Column I, Column AA
both have the value of a the first month in years from 1318 till 1500 "Arabic Calender"
but I want to check which of these values doesn't match and color them with yellow for example.

In this case, both cells in row 3 should have a different color after the checking operation.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: You can use Conditional Formatting for this.

Comment: @TimWilliams How can I do this?

Answer (score 64):

1. Select your range from cell A (or the whole columns by first selecting column A). Make sure that the 'lighter coloured' cell is A1 then go to conditional formatting, new rule:

   [image]
2. Put the following formula and the choice of your formatting (notice that the 'lighter coloured' cell comes into play here, because it is being used in the formula):

   ```
   =$A1<>$B1
   ```

   [image]
3. Then press OK and that should do it.

   [image]

Comment: If you have trouble with this, make sure you leave off the `$` for the direction that will be changing. E.g. If you have column data, make sure you have a `$` only on the column (`$A1`, not `$A$1`).

Answer (score 5):

you could try this:

I have these two columns (column "A" and column "B"). I want to color them when the values between cells in the same row mismatch.

Follow these steps:

1. Select the elements in column "A" (excluding A1);
2. Click on "Conditional formatting -> New Rule -> Use a formula to determine which cells to format";
3. Insert the following formula: **=IF(A2<>B2;1;0)**;
4. Select the format options and click "OK";
5. Select the elements in column "B" (excluding B1) and repeat the steps from 2 to 4.

Comment: this is helpful but the `;` in the formula can be replaced with `,`. Also the `IF` is unnecessary: see the accepted answer.

Comment: This is the correct answer for Office 2016 - you need the "if" formula.

Answer (score 4):

In my case I had  to  compare  column E  and  I.

I used conditional formatting  with new rule.
Formula  was   "=IF($E1<>$I1,1,0)"   for  highlights in orange
and  "=IF($E1=$I1,1,0)"  to highlight in green.

Next  problem  is  how  many columns  you   want  to  highlight.
If  you  open  Conditional Formatting Rules Manager  you can  edit for  each  rule  domain of  applicability: Check  "Applies to"

In my  case I used  "=$E:$E,$I:$I"  for  both  rules so I  highlight  only  two  columns  for differences  - column I and column E.